# Spring Boot App with Batch does not working in Amazon AWS Lambda environment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-batch

My spring batch boot application is read file and insert in to database. I am new to AWS Lambda functionality, their is very little to no resource available.

When I test the jar on AWS lambda got `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.repository")
@ComponentScan("my.package")
@EnableScheduling
public class Main implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, String>{

@Autowired
JobLauncher launcher;

@Autowired
Job job;

public static void startApp(){
    System.exit(SpringApplication
            .exit(SpringApplication.run(Main.class)));
}
```

---

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, String> {

@Override
public String handleRequest(KinesisEvent input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

    Main.startApp();
    // TODO: implement your handler
    return "Hello from Lambda";
}
```

---

```
My _build.gradle_:

dependencies {

compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.0.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data- 
jpa:2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.1.0.jre8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.1.0'

}
jar {
manifest{
    baseName = "${projectName}"
    version = ("${project.archiveVersion}")
 }
} 

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
from compileJava
from processResources              
into('lib') {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
 }           
}
build.dependsOn buildZip
```

---

```
Handler info on AWS Lambda- 
my.package.Handler::handleRequest
```

---

```
Class not found: my.package.Handler: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.Handler
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

Comment: Can you provide some lines from the stack trace especially which class was not found?

Comment: Class not found: my.package.Handler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.Handler
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

Comment: What do you mean _"little to no resource available"_? There're lots of tutorials on the web and you also have the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html. In short: you don't need a Spring Boot app anymore, just upload your `Handler` class and use the AWS Control Panel to tell AWS when it should run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [Spring Boot gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) to create an executable jar with all dependencies included.

Then you can create a AWS Lambda function that runs this jar with `java -jar mybatchjob.jar`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: would you please be able to give me some link to a working example which solves above issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the gradle dependencies are not in the jar you are deploying in the lambda function. The jar needs to have all the dependency jars injected.

Comment: How can I inject all dependencies in a jar . In my build.gradle I have specified jar setting like:- jar {
    manifest{
        baseName = "${projectName}"
        version = ("${project.archiveVersion}")
    }
}

Comment: I have added the gradle dependencies in the jar which I deployed to lambda function as above (edited after your answer) still getting classNotFoundException when I tried to test lambda function.

Comment: You will have to build all the dependencies and deploy in the jar. Many IDEs like eclipse, intellij, netbeans have the feature to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to dependencies are missing in the jar you deployed in Lambda function. create a single Jar with all dependencies and re deploy it once again

No need to change the handler info : my.package.Handler::handleRequest

Answer (score 0):

it is bad idea to use Spring Boot in Lambda.
technically you can, but Lambda supposed to start quick and finish quick.
Spring Boot apps has long initialisation and loading time, which is irrelevant for server application running all the time, but quite critical for serverless lambdas, spawned on demand.
we use lambdas written in Kotlin, but without Spring. you can look at Micronaut, which also offers dependency injection in similar fashion, but without reflection