# How to call Springboot batch job from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-batch

I have an existing project written in Spring boot batch with a class with @EnableBatchProcessing annotation that contains all batch related code. I need to deploy this project as AWS Lambda function. I added a handler method in the code and able to call it from lambda but not sure how to connect/call Batch class from this handler. Please help

Comment: Have you looked at https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function?

Comment: httPants , it has example of a simple function. I have a batch config file with @EnableBatchConfiguration annotation and Job and Steps defined inside it. I am not able to call this batch job from my handler function. Tried calling it form my handler class like SpringApplication.run(DemoBatchApplication.class) but getting Failed to execute CommandLineRunner error while testing in aws lambda. The same run well if i run on local machine

Comment: I would use a [JobParametersBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html) to create JobParameters from the lambda input, then use a [SimpleJobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.html) to [run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.html#run-org.springframework.batch.core.Job-org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters-) the job from the lambda handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot App with Batch does not working in Amazon AWS Lambda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609780/spring-boot-app-with-batch-does-not-working-in-amazon-aws-lambda-environment)